# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field on a null object reference in method

Tags: java, android, arrays

I've created a class.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class Example {
    int xStart = 0;
    int yStart = 0;
    int xEnd = 0;
    int yEnd = 0;
    int xCurrent = 0;
    int yCurrent = 0;
}
```

then in my MainActivity I define this.
`Example FromTo[] = new Example[25];`

which gives me no error.
then I use the code below for example,
`FromTo[0].xEnd = 120;`

then I try to reference it by doing this.
in several different places in the program and it always gives me the same error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field on a null object reference in method

I am expecting that it will allow me to assign a value.
What am I overlooking? If the program allows you to create something, it should allow you to use it!
A) Please be kind.
B) Try to be very detailed
C) Thank you for your help in advance
D) I do not want to use a standard integer array

Answer (score 1):

```
Example FromTo[] = new Example[25];
```

This creates an array with the length 25. But it's empty. So

`FromTo[0]`

is `null` and any operation on it will throw a NPE.

You need to fill the array first with 1 - 25 `Example` objects to then work with. Depending on your constructor, something like:

```
FromTo[0] = new Example()
```

Then you'll have an object in this position 0 that you can change the `xend` for.

Don't know your exact requirements to say if this makes sense at all, but this would fix the exception.